# Get first three rows : with clause

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following Query:

```
with TEMPRESULT AS 
(
    select CONTACTS.line_id , count(*) totalcount
    from CONTACTS
    where (((E_DATE-S_DATE)*24*60*60)<=60 and to_char(S_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')='2015-12-12') 
    group by CONTACTS.line_id
    order by totalcount DESC
)
```

I want **TEMPRESULT** holds only the first three rows returned by `select`, how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a condition on `rownum`:

```
with TEMPRESULT AS 
(
    select * from 
    (
      select CONTACTS.line_id , count(*) totalcount
      from CONTACTS
      where (((E_DATE-S_DATE)*24*60*60)<=60 and to_char(S_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')='2015-12-12') 
      group by CONTACTS.line_id
      order by totalcount DESC
    ) x
    where rownum < 3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have oracle 12c you can use the fetch first

```
WITH TEMPRESULT AS
  (SELECT CONTACTS.line_id ,
    COUNT(*) totalcount
  FROM CONTACTS
  WHERE (((E_DATE-S_DATE)*24*60*60)<=60
  AND TO_CHAR(S_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')  ='2015-12-12')
  GROUP BY CONTACTS.line_id
  ORDER BY 2 DESC
  FETCH FIRST 3 rows only
  )
SELECT * FROM tempresult
```